# How to insert new row - xlwings

Tags: excel, python-3.x, xlwings

What I'm trying to achieve is to extend the length of a table within a current Excel form (not appending to the bottom of the whole spreadsheet), while not replacing the content below the table.

To do this, I want to **insert new rows** (for example on row 30). **How can I do this** with xlwings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out how this can be done. Unfortunately xlwings doesn't seem to have the functionality built in, but it's possible to do using the API.

This is how I inserted a new row:

```
sht.range("30:30").api.Insert(InsertShiftDirection.xlShiftToRight)
```

Comment: Note that per [the docs](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html#xlwings.Range.insert) you can now just do `sht.range("30:30").insert()` (the default is shift down).

Comment: The default is actually decided by Excel, depending on the shape of the range. So it's better to explicitly do `.insert('down')`.